# Pig Sum field from bag not works

Tags: apache-pig

**Updated**

The input is a json line text file.

```text
{"store":"079","items":[{"name":"早晨全餐","unit_price":18,"quantity":1,"total":18},{"name":"麦趣鸡盒","unit_price":78,"quantity":5,"total":390},{"name":"巨无霸","unit_price":17,"quantity":5,"total":85},{"name":"香骨鸡腿","unit_price":12,"quantity":2,"total":24},{"name":"小薯条","unit_price":7,"quantity":5,"total":35}],"date":"\/Date(1483256820000)\/","oId":"27841ef9-f88e-478f-8f20-17c3ad090ebc"}
{"store":"041","items":[{"name":"小薯条","unit_price":7,"quantity":2,"total":14},{"name":"巨无霸","unit_price":17,"quantity":4,"total":68}],"date":"\/Date(1483221780000)\/","oId":"afee2e6d-0f81-4780-82e9-2169bf3c43f3"}
{"store":"008","items":[{"name":"奶昔香草","unit_price":9,"quantity":5,"total":45},{"name":"小薯条","unit_price":7,"quantity":2,"total":14}],"date":"\/Date(1483248600000)\/","oId":"802ea077-1eef-4cc9-af89-af7398e56792"}
```

Expect to group by all store and calculate the sum of total in each items,for example:

```text
store_name  total_amount
_________________________
001 2212.26
002 3245.46
003 888888
```

My Pig script:

```text
store_table = LOAD '/example/store-data/2017-store-sales-data.json'
    USING JsonLoader('
        store_name:chararray,
         items: {(
                name:chararray,
                unit_price:Bigdecimal,
                quantity:int,
                total:Bigdecimal)
                },
      date:Datetime,
      oId:chararray'
       );

platten_table = foreach store_table generate flatten(items), store_name;
store_group =  group platten_table by store_name;

result = foreach store_group {
total_sum = sum(platten_table.items::total);
Generate group,total_sum;
}
```

Pig error is :
2017-11-28 08:53:54,357 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   mismatched input 'Generate' expecting SEMI_COLON

Comment: Can you share sample input and the expected output ? Also it would be nice to see the code where you are facing this issue.

Comment: @MuraliRao , thanks you reply, I updated my questions.

Comment: @MosserLee You are missing a semicolon at the end of this statement total_sum = sum(platten_table.items::total)

Comment: @MuraliRao,missing a semicolon indeed. updated. thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eval Functions are case sensitive, you need to use the eval function **SUM** in upper case.

**Code snippet -**

```
result = foreach store_group {
    total_sum = SUM(platten_table.items::total);
    Generate group,total_sum;
}
```

> Refer : https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html